# Can't override UserAuthenticationTokenService service

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm trying to add custom logic for login page, for that as described [here](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components/) I try to override UserAuthenticationTokenService service. I want to add custom logic to this method:

```
loadToken(userId: string, password: string): Observable<UserToken>;
```

But when I try to import this class definition it comes from

```
import {UserAuthenticationTokenService} from '@spartacus/core/src/auth/services/user-authentication/user-authentication-token.service';
```

After this auto import project cannot be compiled with error:

> ERROR in ./src/app/services/services.module.ts
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@spartacus/core/src/auth/services/user-authentication/user-authentication-token.service' in '/home/gyerts/PycharmProjects/fiver/e5p-client/src/app/services'

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's true that it's not being exported directly in Spartacus 2.x, I have found that it is still available. If you look at the compiled `spartacus-core.d.ts` file, you will see that `UserAuthenticationTokenService` is being exported under a gibberish name:

```
export { UserAuthenticationTokenService as ɵbj } from './src/auth/services/user-authentication/user-authentication-token.service';
```

While this is probably not the best idea, I have found that you can actually import this in your own code. You can also rename it back to the original name for legibility:

```
import { ɵbj as UserAuthenticationTokenService } from '@spartacus/core';
```

I have used this myself on my current project and it seems to work fine:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyUserAuthenticationTokenService extends UserAuthenticationTokenService {}
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MyUserAuthenticationTokenService } from './services/my-user-authentication-token.service';
import { ɵbj as UserAuthenticationTokenService } from '@spartacus/core';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: UserAuthenticationTokenService, useExisting: MyUserAuthenticationTokenService }
  ]
})
export class MyAuthModule {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Spartacus 2.x, `UserAuthenticationTokenService` is present in `@spartacus/core`, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be exposed in the [public api](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/release/2.1.x/projects/core/public_api.ts).  Therefore, you won't be able to import it.

If you're using Spartacus 3.x, `UserAuthenticationTokenService` was removed.  Spartacus 3.0 introduces a new session management implementation.  You can learn more about it [here](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/session-management/).

Comment: We have custom backend, custom backend requires "remember me" parameter in http request, how would you suggest to add additional data to the request? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66062114/add-remember-me-checkbox-to-the-login-page